# Java Script - replace text with condition

Tags: javascript, replace

There is a list.
I want change text to "0" if text is "00"
Doesn't work.

```js
let turnToZero = document.getElementsByClassName("tutorial_length");
for (var i = 0; i < turnToZero.length; i++){
  let x = turnToZero[i].textContent;
  if ( x = "00" ) { x ="0"} 
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="tutorial_length">40</li>
   <li class="tutorial_length">00</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You forgot to assign the replacement back to the DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues in your code:

1. You are using assignment (`=`) operator instead of comparison (`==` or `===`) operator.
2. You have to update the elements `textcontent` property.

**Change:**

```
if ( x = "00" ) { x ="0"}
```

**To:**

```
if ( x == "00" ) { turnToZero[i].textContent ="0"; }
```

```js
let turnToZero = document.getElementsByClassName("tutorial_length");
for (var i = 0; i < turnToZero.length; i++){
  let x = turnToZero[i].textContent;
  if ( x == "00" ) { turnToZero[i].textContent = "0"; } 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="tutorial_length">40</li>
  <li class="tutorial_length">00</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for explain. For the second  issue, why I can't use  `if ( x == "00" ) { x ="0"}` ?  As I can  see, I alrady assign `x` to the textconent.

Comment: @blurfun, you can not modify the DOM property that way, you can try `let x = turnToZero[i]; if ( x.textContent == "00" ) { x.textContent  = "0"; }`